# How to validate users to edit only there own biography

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models *user* and *biography*, both of them have one to one association.

Each user has single biography. My problem is that, I want to allow user to edit only their own biography but from url one user can edit other's biography

EX."0.0.0.0:3000/biographies/8/edit". Here a user can easily change id.

How can i stop this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `biographies` controller, under the "edit" action (and update, too), insert this right underneath your call to `@biography = Biography.find(params[:id])`:

```
unless @biography.user == current_user
    redirect_to root_path, notice: "You cannot do that" and return
end
```

Comment: Yep, in the before_filter you would use the same code. But before those lines, you would add `@biography = Biography.find(params[:id])`.

Comment: so: `before_filter :check_ownership, only: [:edit, :update]`, and then make your `check_ownership` method at the bottom of the controller.

Answer (score 0):

```
before_filter :fetch_bio, :only => [:edit, :update]

def fetch_bio
  @biography = current_user.biographies.find(params[:id])
end
```

Comment: thanks sumskyi,yours answer help me alot to solve the problem.